# Highchart/stockChart: Zoom with buttons into monthly-data and show affected columns

Tags: html, button, highcharts, zoom-sdk

I have a simple time-series in highchart:

```
series: [{    
"data": [[Date.UTC(2021,0,1), 22312], // January 
[Date.UTC(2021,1,1), 12312], // Feburary
[Date.UTC(2021,2,1), 23322], // ... etc.
],
```

Now I want to zoom into one month, and show just one column with the given code:

```
rangeSelector: {
      buttons: [{
        text: '1m',
        type: 'month',
        count: 1, // This should show only 1 month, but it shows 2.
        // If this is changed to "0", one month will be show, but 
       // The css "highcharts-button-pressed" is disabled, and you cannot
       // see that "1m" was clicked. 
},
```

According to documentation "rangeSelector.buttons.count" should span over an area of one month if type is "month" and count is "1". But what I´m getting here is a span over two months.

Here is an example:
https://jsfiddle.net/ds90vf5r/1/

**Question 1:** Why is higchart showing two columns instead of one when choosing/clicking on just 1-month (1m)?
**Question 2:** How can I zoom into the current date and show just one moth (or one column)?

Comment: Take a look at this demo https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/z8w21qLy/ it should explain to you how the Highcharts calculates this one month. To display this one column in the middle you will need to display 2 weeks range for example